# Sublime Text 2: Setting file syntax inside the file itself (as Vim modelines)

Tags: sublimetext2

In VIM one can force a file type by writing a modeline like this

```
# vim:syntax=html filetype=html
```

I'ld like to obtain the same thing for Sublime Text. For example I'ld like Sublime Text 2 to use MarkDown syntax for some file I have with .txt extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Modelines plugin for Sublime Text: https://github.com/SublimeText/Modelines

Answer (score 4):

To do this for every file with a specific extension, with a file open go to menu `View`, `Syntax`, `Open all with current extension as...` and set your preference there.

It doesn't seem to be possible natively to set it per file or project, but propably you should take a look at this package: https://github.com/phillipkoebbe/DetectSyntax

Answer (score 1):

Another one available in package control for ST2/3 is https://github.com/kvs/STEmacsModelines

using it is very simple, from the docs:

Somewhere within the first five lines of a file, add a line matching the following:

```
-*- key: value; key2: value2 -*-
```

or

```
-*- syntax -*-
```